# Determining How Many Rows Deleted

Tags: plsql

I'm using a table to drive deletes from another table.  I'd like to be able to keep track of how many rows were deleted for each record in the table that drives the deletions.  Using SQL%ROWCOUNT doesn't appear useful for my purposes as it will just return the total number of rows deleted in a DELETE statement.  Is there another method that I can use?  To illustrate

```
DELETE 
FROM my_schema.tbl_companies A 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM my_schema.table_that_includes_companies_to_be_deleted RMV 
        WHERE RMV.company = A.company
    );
```

If there are two records in my table_that_includes_companies_to_be_deleted table and each one of these records maps to 20 records in the tbl_companies table then that will result in SQL%ROWCOUNT returning a value of 40.  I'd like to be able to see exactly how many records were deleted for the first record in table_that_includes_companies_to_be_deleted and for the second record in table_that_includes_companies_to_be_deleted

Comment: So `SQL%ROWCOUNT ` will return `40` (as you say) because, indeed `40` records where deleted from `tbl_companies` . why would you expect any other number to be returned? I guess that if you want to keep track of deletes per record (per repetition to be exact), then you will have to implement the delete logic with `cursor` and `for` `loop`s in a procedure or an anonymous pl/sql block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Plirkee's comment, you could use a cursor and for loop to delete them.  Or you could do this:

```
DECLARE
  l_tab SYS.KU$_VCNT; -- This is a pre-existing collection type
BEGIN
  DELETE 
  FROM my_schema.tbl_companies A 
  WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM my_schema.table_that_includes_companies_to_be_deleted RMV 
          WHERE RMV.company = A.company
      )
  RETURNING company BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;

  for r in (select column_value, count(*) cnt from table(l_tab) group by column_value)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('company '||r.column_value||' deleted '||r.cnt);
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Interesting approach ... Of course the is a downside in using Oracle undocumented objects like  `SYS.KU$_VCNT`.  You cannot depend on them - as they could change (by Oracle I mean)  - without any notification .

Comment: @Plirkee True, I'd probably create a collection type of my own in reality.

Comment: Very interesting solution Tony, thanks.  I've not worked with collections in PL/SQL before so I'll give this a try and see what results.